# An Olympic Connecting Wall

Tags: pattern, wordplay, knowledge, sports, connect-wall

In honor of Rio 2016, here’s a connecting wall about the Olympics! The 16 clues below can be sorted into four connected groups of 4. What are the groups and their connections?

[image: 4 by 4 table. First row: Parry, Right of way, Middle, Extension. Second row:Fly, Bekele, Croquet, Heavy. Thrid Row: Young, Usage Bout, Bolt. Fourth row:Thrust, Waler, Bantam, Johnson.]

Text version:

|  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Parry | Right of way | Middle | Extension |
| Fly | Bekele | Croquet | Heavy |
| Young | Usage | Bout | Bolt |
| Thrust | Walker | Bantam | Johnson |

Comment: I see these are back in fashion.

Comment: @JoeZ.: I'm sorry.

Comment: @Deusovi It's alright, I was actually planning on making a second one myself.

Comment: What does it mean to have a "connecting group"?

Comment: @justhalf In the context of these connecting walls, a connected group is a set of 4 clues that are all linked by some common trait. For example, the four clues Maltese, Red, Southern, and Victoria are connected by the fact that all four can be followed by the word "cross" (Maltese cross, Red Cross, Southern Cross, Victoria Cross). [Here's a real connecting wall being solved on the actual show](https://youtu.be/MXVCh8Z7AfQ?t=1167) (Only Connect), if you're interested :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Bout, Thrust, Extension, Right of way

> Terms used in fencing

2. Walker, Bekele, Johnson, Young

> Olympic running record holders (Melaine Walker, Michael Johnson, Kenenisa Bekele, Kevin Young)

3. Fly, Bantam, Middle, Heavy

> Boxing weights

4. Croquet, Bolt, Usage, Parry

> The first three letters are IOC country codes (Croatia, Bolivia, United States, Paraguay)

Comment: Gah, I was just about to post all of these.

Comment: @Deusovi Never underestimate the person who pioneered this category of puzzles in the first place. >:D

Comment: I would've beaten you to them if I hadn't gone to answer the door. :P

Comment: Your connections for 1-3 are right, but only 3 has the right clues.

Comment: "Bout" is also a member of group 1, and "Walker" is also a member of group 2.

Comment: @DooplissForce Thought it might be that.

Comment: If this were an actual wall it would have told me the connections were wrong as I tapped them in. :P

Comment: I can barely figure out what croquet has to do with the Olympics at all.

Comment: @JoeZ. Interestingly enough [it was contested at the 1900 Summer Olympics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Croquet_at_the_1900_Summer_Olympics), but that fact's not relevant for this. :)

Comment: Also, your second group is now correct!

Comment: @DooplissForce how about now?

Comment: @JoeZ. Not yet :(

Comment: @DooplissForce How about... now?

Comment: @JoeZ. Nope, luckily this isn't the real show otherwise the wall would've frozen :)

Comment: @DooplissForce I believe this is the last one possible.

Comment: @JoeZ. Yep, correct :)

Comment: FINALLY. Problem is, I _still_ can't figure out the fourth one.

Comment: Parry would also fit into group 1.

Comment: @mestackoverflow It was there originally, but apparently the fourth group has that word in it.

Comment: @DooplissForce I think I've got it!

Comment: @JoeZ. Yep that's correct! Well spotted :)

Comment: How is `United States` -> `UNI`? I know it's `USA`.

Comment: The first three letters of "Usage" are USA.

Comment: Excuse me, is there a privacy option of some sort? The avatar of user88 is grey and can't be clicked. Just curious.