# An "Only Connect" Wall

Tags: pattern, wordplay, knowledge, connect-wall

When I saw [this](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/40306/an-olympic-connecting-wall) post I became really excited to do one, so here is a connecting wall.

The 4 groups of a total of 16 words can be sorted into four connected groups of 4. The goal is to find the connections of the groups.

[image: 4 by 4 connect wall: Text version below]

Here is a text version

|  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Sweet | Face | Chatting | Don Juan |
| Instant | Win | Gold | Glory |
| Bald | Amorist | Conquest | Predator |
| American | Romeo | Exult | Space |

Note:  I have no specific topic because when I watched a video of the show on BBC, all four topics where completely unrelated.  This also may be too easy for you guys because I myself made up the connections.

Comment: I'm sure every on would have gotten it, so +1 to everyone!

Comment: Yep, on the show all the topics are unrelated. But they usually have things that *could* go into multiple categories, so you have to get all four of the actual categories before you can place things.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Group 1:

> American Gold Bald Predator (eagles)

Group 2:

> (My) Space  Face (book)  Instant (messaging) Chatting.

Credit goes to lois6b and AJ but a small change is in place:

Group 3:

> Romeo (and Juliet), Sweet (love), Don Juan (the great lover), Amorist (synonym for lover)

Group 4:

> Win, Conquest, Glory, Exult - winning (and enjoying it)

Comment: Correct! one down.  2nd down.

Comment: And we have a winner!

Comment: Could you edit this answer to add in a detailed explanation as to why you think it is correct, citing the information in the question? Thanks!

Comment: @Emrakul What's wrong with the present answers? I've added the missing words so that is clear what I mean. Stating the obvious isn't much help.

Comment: OK, I've edited the post but really, why?

Comment: @Radoslav As I've said before, answers without explanations may be removed. Thank for your edits, though!

Answer (score 4):

I have two group:

Group 1:

> **Romeo, Amorist, Sweet, Don Juan.** Romeo-Juliet a popular love story. Don Juan refers to a captivating man known as a great lover of women. Amorist refers to a person who is in love or who writes about love. And sweet love.

Group 2:

> **Conquest, Win, Glory, Exult.** These are somehow related to the feeling of  triumphant.

Comment: Both of these are correct!

Comment: Could you edit this answer to add in a detailed explanation as to why you think it is correct, citing the information in the question? Thanks!

Comment: @Emrakul Your comment is obsolete now.

Answer (score 3):

I think I have two groups:  [EDITED]

Group 1 :

> Romeo, Conquest, Don Juan, Amorist -> Love or relations related (Romeo and Juliet, Don Juan the flirter .. )

Group 2:

> Win,  <s>gold</s> sweet , Glory, Exult -> Winning (sweet victory, gold first place..)

Comment: I will not lie I threw in ones that would fit in two, but if you find the others you will see that they belong elsewhere, almost got the first one

Comment: gold i see now is not in the right place.as Radoslav said

Comment: @lois6b you can replace gold  with sweet (success).

Comment: @RadoslavHristov could be.. sweet victory

Comment: nope not sweet.

Comment: @Jason_ check my edit

Comment: lois6b and @A J , I'm sure you guys would have gotten it if it wasn't so quick.

Comment: @Jason_ eventually .... hahah for the next one maybe